# Finding largest element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a JavaScript program that will display the largest number out of 10 numbers inputted by the user. This is what I have so far but it isn't working.

```js
var counter = 1;
var number = new Array();
number.length = 9;
var largest = 0;

while (counter <= 10) {
    number = window.prompt("Enter Numbers 1-10 Number:" + counter + ".");
    number[counter] = parseInt(number);
    counter++;
}

largest = Math.max.apply(Array);
document.writeln("<h1>Largest number is " + largest + "</h1>");
```

Comment: Have you read anything about the javascript arrays?

Comment: I am new to Javascript, Just started the chapter this week

Comment: For a newcomer, this question is pretty well formatted as well as it includes information on what you have tried already along with the code. +1 for that. Make sure to read the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page it includes quite useful information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. Arrays are `0` indexed. You skipped the `0` index by starting the counter at `0`, this will screw up the array calculation. If you go with `Math.max.apply(array, number)`, it will work without the `0` indexing.
2. You overwrote the `number` variable with every prompt, either use the `window.prompt` to feed into the `parseInt` or feed it into a temporary variable.
3. You had incorrect syntax for the apply variable.

```js
var counter = 0;
var number = new Array();
number.length = 9;
var newnumber;
var largest = 0;

while (counter <= 10) {
    newnumber = window.prompt("Enter Numbers 1-10 Number:" + counter + ".");
    number[counter] = parseInt(newnumber);

    counter++;
}

largest = Math.max.apply(Math, number);
document.writeln("<h1>Largest number is " + largest + "</h1>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're simply missing the expected `thisArg` for [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

The [Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Syntax), as described by MDN is

> fun.apply(thisArg[, argsArray])

As shown in this simple example

```
Math.max.apply (null,[5,4,3,7,9,]) //9
                ^^^^
```

*where `null` is used in the example for simplicity, as Math doesn't expect an specific context*

What you are trying to do is passing the array `number` to `Math.max`, which would then be the `thisArg` *(though you seem to have it mistaken with `Array`)* which would result *either way* in `Math.max` being called with zero arguments, which yields according to *§15.8.2.11*

> Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the 
>   largest of the resulting values.
>
> - If no arguments are given, the result is −∞.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're mixing up the array with the temporary variable to hold the input.
2. [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) takes two arguments, the context (irrelevant in this case) and the arguments array.

Should be like this:

```js
var counter = 1;
var arr = [];
var count = 3;

while (counter <= count) {
    number = window.prompt("Enter Numbers 1-" + count + " Number #" + counter + ": ");
    if (number === null) break;
    arr[counter++] = parseInt(number);
}

if (arr.length > 0) {
    var largest = Math.max.apply(Array, arr);
    alert("<h1>Largest number is " + largest + "</h1>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var counter = 1;
var number = [];
var largest = 0;

while (counter <= 10) {
    number.push(Number(window.prompt("Enter Numbers 1-10 Number:" + counter + "."), 10));
    counter++;
}

Array.prototype.max = function () {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
};

largest = number.max();
document.writeln("<h1>Largest number is " + largest + "</h1>");
```

Comment: It's always better to add some code to explain what you actually did.

Answer (score 1):

The main problems with your code are:

1. You are missing a `this` argument from the `Math.max.apply` function call.
2. You are destroying the `number` array every time you read a new value from the user. You need a separate variable for the user input.

However, you don't really need to build an array at all for this task. Inside the loop, just compare `largest` with the number just supplied by the user and update `largest` if appropriate:

```js
var counter;
var number;
var largest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
    number = window.prompt("Enter Numbers 1-10 Number:" + counter + ".");
    number = parseInt(number);
    if (number > largest) {
        largest = number;
    }
}

document.writeln("<h1>Largest number is " + largest + "</h1>");
```