# How to return the largest number in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some issues with this code and can't find any solution anywhere. Here's the code:

```js
function getLargestNumber(numbers) {}

const largestNumber = getLargestNumber([1, 9, 5]);
console.log(largestNumber);
```

Comment: Change tag java !== javascript

Comment: Hi Isaac, what exactly is the issue that you encounter? If the value of console.log is empty, you might need a return value in your function

Comment: `return Math.max(...numbers)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding Largest Element in an Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322775/finding-largest-element-in-an-array-using-javascript)

Comment: can you demonstrate _any_ evidence of having tried this out yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it very easy using the [spread (`...`) syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and the [`Math.max()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

```js
function getLargestNumber(numbers) {
  return Math.max(...numbers);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll hopefully find out if this works when my 4 hours are up and I can retry this! I didn't see that operator, Also didn't even know such a thing existed xD

Comment: If you want to learn more abut this operator you can read more abut this here : https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getLargestNumber(numbers) {
  let largest = numbers[0];

  for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > largest) largest = numbers[i]
  }
  return largest;
}

const largestNumber = getLargestNumber([1, 9, 5]);
console.log(largestNumber);
```

Comment: This only works if the second number is the largest number, because it will always log the second number not the largest number. But that you for your response.

Comment: not sure if I follow you, getLargestNumber([1,8,0,12, 9, 5]); i just tried this and it printed 12. The program just assumes first element as largest (0th index) and loop through next element(1st index0 through last, if any of the element is larger than the largest being stored so far, it restore the largest and finally prints largest number. May not work for edge case but the algorithm works.

Comment: It's always better to add some text to explain you answer.